# Lua __gc metamethod is never called

Tags: c++, lua

I have a *Vector* class that is wrapped to work in Lua. The C++ part of the class is:

```
template<typename T> CVector<T>::CVector(int len)
{
    m_vector=new vector<T>(len);
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++) m_vector->at(i)=T();
}
template<typename T> CVector<T>::~CVector(void)
{
    if(m_vector){
        m_vector->clear();
        delete m_vector;
    }
    m_vector=0;
}
```

I use the wrapper library from https://bitbucket.org/alexames/luawrapper/src . The wrapper part for the *Vector* is:

```
CVector<double>* Vector_new(lua_State* L)
{
    CVector<double>* retVec=0;
    int type = lua_type(L, 1);

    if(type==LUA_TTABLE)retVec=new CVector<double>(L,1);
    if(type==LUA_TNUMBER){
        int len = luaL_checknumber(L, 1);
        retVec=new CVector<double>(len);
    }
    return retVec;
}

int Vector_gc(lua_State* L)
{
    CVector<double>* vec = luaW_check<CVector<double> >(L, 1);
    //luaW_release(L, vec);
    if(vec) delete vec;
    vec=0;

    wxMessageBox("GC is called");
    return 0;
}

static luaL_Reg Vector_table[] = {{ NULL, NULL }};

static luaL_Reg Vector_metatable[] = {
{"__gc", Vector_gc},
{ NULL, NULL }
};

int luaopen_Vector(lua_State* L)
{
    luaW_register<CVector<double> >(L, "Vector", Vector_table, Vector_metatable, Vector_new);
    lua_pop(L,1);
    return 0;
}
```

According to the library's documentation, if `luaW_register` is used, then the owner of the pointer is Lua unless it is explicitly released by `luaW_release`. I test the wrapper with the following Lua code:

```
for i=1,2 do local v=Vector.new(2) end
```

My understanding was when `local v` was out of scope, it should have been garbage collected. I explicitly called `collectgarbage` but the metamethod `__gc` is never called and the memory usage increases for big *vectors* unless I call from lua with `v:__gc()`. My question is why the `__gc` metamethod is never called?

Comment: I don't understand the question - it's not because `luaW_release(L, vec);` is commented out, is it?

Comment: @JackDeeth: No, it is not. Even if `luaW_release` is not commented out, the `__gc` itself is never called since I cannot see the MessageBox.

Comment: This library has its own (standard) `luaW_gc` function implemented, so your custom `__gc` metamethod is ignored (probably, it was written over by standard one).

Comment: In which part of the code should I call `luaW_gc`? When I create a *Vector* say with 1,000,000 elements, the memory usage significantly increases, never going down. That gives me the feeling the objects are not garbagecollected.

Comment: Lua uses a mark-and-sweep collector.  In other words, it does *not* collect garbage just because a variable goes out of scope.  It otherwise has no idea that a small object like Vector has a honking chunk of memory associated with it that is not garbage-collected.  So you'll have to help, either by adding an explicit dispose() method or by forcing a gc.

Comment: @HansPassant: The `collectgarbage()` call mentioned in the question forces a full GC run.

Comment: It seems like the wrapper I used was not garbage collection friendly. So binding again by the procedures described in Lua's official website, the garbage collection mechanism now works flawlessly.